# How do I predicate the similarity of the two sentences by comparing the small parts of the them?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, classification

I want to divide two sentences to small parts and compare the similarity of both parts, and then sit side by side and see if there are two sentences are similar.
My data is tagged for the whole sentences, but not for small sections. ( I don’t know the similarity of each pair of parts)

How can I do this?

Comment: You can convert the sentences to a vector representation using GloVe, Word2Vec etc. Then, you can calculate the cosine similarity of both the vectors.

Comment: sure, i calculate distance (or similarity) for each pair of chunk but the problem is in the training phase because we have label for distance of whole sentence not for each pair of chunk